# AsParallel() and internal buffer size

Tags: .net, multithreading, plinq

How to limit the amount of items that AsParallel() reads upfront and puts in its internal buffer?

Here is an example:

```
int returnedCounter;

IEnumerable<int> Enum()
{
    while (true)
        yield return Interlocked.Increment(ref returnedCounter);
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    foreach (var i in Enum().AsParallel().Select(a => a))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(returnedCounter);
}
```

I consume 1 item, sleep, stop enumeration. It prints 526400 on my machine. In my real project each item allocates thousands of kilobytes. AsParallel() reads a lot of items upfront which results to very bad memory consumption and waste of CPU.

Putting WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered) helps a bit. It prints 4544. But it is still too much for me.

Waiting in Enum() freezes the loop in the main thread.

Answer (score 4):

Another question about [Partitioners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415998/parallelizing-a-task-using-asparallel-forall-or-parallel-foreach-performance)!

In your case, you will have to find / write a Partitioner that only takes one item at a time.

Here's an article on [Custom Partitioners](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411.aspx)

---

**UPDATE:**

I just remembered where I saw a `SingleItemPartitioner` implementation: it's in the `ParallelExtensionsExtras` project here: [Samples for Parallel Programming with the .NET Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364)

I've also just read your test code. I probably should have done that first time!

This code:

```
Enum().AsParallel().Select(a => a)
```

means: take `Enum()` and enumerate it as fast as possible, in parallel, and return a new `IEnumerable<int>`.

So your `foreach` isn't pulling items from `Enum()` - it's pulling items from a new `IEnumerable<int>` created by the linq statement.

Also, your `foreach` runs on the main thread, so the work on each item is single-threaded.

If you want to run in parallel, but only yield an item when it is required, try:

```
Parallel.ForEach( SingleItemPartitioner.Create( Enum() ), ( i, state ) =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep( 3000 );
        state.Break();
    }
```

Comment: I adopted one-item-per-partition partitioner from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997416.aspx. Also tried SingleItemPartitioner from the samples you pointed out. Code was like
` foreach (var i in SingleItemPartitioner.Create(Enum()).AsParallel().Select(a => a))`
 
Same output - more than 500000 items are read upfront and cached by plinq.

Comment: > so the work on each item is single-threaded.
Correct. But there is also a part of work that is done in parallel. Let me clarify my question. My code emulates common plinq usage scenario
`foreach (var i in Enum().AsParallel().Select(a => DoExpensiveWorkInParallel(a))) DoRestOfWorkSynchronously(i);'

Comment: Problem is that synchronous part may wait for some event and not to consume items produced by ParallelQuery.Select(). I expect plinq to stop fetching items from source IEnumerable (returned by Enum()) and suspend parallel processing. plinq actually does that but first it fills some internal queue with more than 500000 items. My question was how to make plinq process fewer items upfront.

Comment: PLinq is designed to process work as fast as possible and all you are asking it to do is generate an IEnumerable.  In the example in your question, the `DoExpensiveWorkInParallel` is fast and the `DoRestOfWorkSynchronously` is slow.

Comment: PLinq creates a conveyor or a pipeline. `DoRestOfWorkSynchronously` is slow indeed - it pauses the conveyor for 3 secs. Parallel part of the conveyor keeps producing and stacking the product to internal queue. Size of the queue seems not to be configurable at all :(

Comment: The real problem in the original post was that you were using AsParallel when you really want to use Parallel.ForEach, beyond that I think the recommendation for SingleItemPartitioner *could be* bad advice. You need to be careful with choosing a single item partitioning scheme. If the work is long running, like I/O operations, it makes a lot of sense. You will incur a lot more overhead going back and pulling the one item from the partitioner each time, because all the worker threads need to coordinate around that one synchronization point and that introduces a ton of contention.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround.

First, let me clarify the original question. I need a pausable pipeline that works on infinite sequence. Pipeline is:

1. read from sequence synchronously: `Enum()`
2. process items in parallel: `AsParallel().Select(a => a)`
3. proceed with synchronous processing: `foreach` body

Step 3 may pause the pipeline. That is emulated by `Sleep()`. Problem is that step 2 fetches too many elements ahead when pipleine is paused. 
 PLinq must have some internal queue. Queue size cannot be configured explicitly. The size depends on `ParallelMergeOptions` though. `ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered` lowers the queue size, but the size is still too big for me.

My workaround is to know how many items are being processed, stop parallel processing when limit is reached, restart parallel processing when pipeline is started again.

```
int sourceCounter;

IEnumerable<int> SourceEnum() // infinite input sequence
{
    while (true)
        yield return Interlocked.Increment(ref sourceCounter);
}

[TestMethod]
public void PlainPLinq_PausedConsumtionTest()
{
    sourceCounter = 0;
    foreach (var i in SourceEnum().AsParallel().WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered).Select(a => a))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("fetched from source sequence: {0}", sourceCounter); // prints 4544 on my machine
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyParallelSelect_NormalConsumtionTest()
{
    sourceCounter = 0;
    foreach (var i in MyParallelSelect(SourceEnum(), 64, a => a))
    {
        if (sourceCounter > 1000000)
            break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("fetched from source sequence: {0}", sourceCounter);
}

[TestMethod]
public void MyParallelSelect_PausedConsumtionTest()
{
    sourceCounter = 0;
    foreach (var i in MyParallelSelect(SourceEnum(), 64, a => a))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("fetched from source sequence: {0}", sourceCounter);
}

class DataHolder<D> // reference type to store class or struct D
{
    public D Data;
}

static IEnumerable<DataHolder<T>> FetchSourceItems<T>(IEnumerator<T> sourceEnumerator, DataHolder<int> itemsBeingProcessed, int queueSize)
{
    for (; ; )
    {
        var holder = new DataHolder<T>();
        if (Interlocked.Increment(ref itemsBeingProcessed.Data) > queueSize)
        {
            // many enought items are already being processed - stop feeding parallel processing
            Interlocked.Decrement(ref itemsBeingProcessed.Data);
            yield break;
        }
        if (sourceEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            holder.Data = sourceEnumerator.Current;
            yield return holder;
        }
        else
        {
            yield return null; // return null DataHolder to indicate EOF
            yield break;
        }
    }
}

IEnumerable<OutT> MyParallelSelect<T, OutT>(IEnumerable<T> source, int queueSize, Func<T, OutT> selector)
{
    var itemsBeingProcessed = new DataHolder<int>();
    using (var sourceEnumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        for (;;) // restart parallel processing
        {
            foreach (var outData in FetchSourceItems(sourceEnumerator, itemsBeingProcessed, queueSize).AsParallel().WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered).Select(
                inData => inData != null ? new DataHolder<OutT> { Data = selector(inData.Data) } : null))
            {
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref itemsBeingProcessed.Data);
                if (outData == null)
                    yield break; // EOF reached
                yield return outData.Data;
            }
        }
    }
}
```